# Switch case always showing Default case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

Okay so this is a two part question and I'm trying to best explain my doubt:

The code is simple, the user keeps entering grades, which the program keeps count of and once the user has given the EOF entry, the program displays the final count of each grade in the end.

1) When I run the code, the program correctly tracks the count of each grade I put, but always falls to the default case, even if the entry is right! Why is this happening?

2) So I'm not entirely sure how "cin.get()" works, but if I'm right, it takes in the first character of whatever the user inputs. 
Here, I put 'grade' as an integer variable because it's what the textbook did so, and I'm trying to understand why he does so. Since grade is an integer variable, and I end up putting character values as the input, I checked beforehand that the value of the character I input ends up being stored as its ASCII value. 
However, even though I've put characters in my switch cases, the program still manages to keep work-> Even though grade has an integer value(The ASCII one) and it technically is being compared with 'A','a','B' and so on. 
So my question is, why does the code still work?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{

    int grade;
    unsigned int countA=0;
    unsigned int countB=0;
    unsigned int countC=0;


    cout << "Keep entering Grades, or EOF to Quit: ";

    while ((grade=cin.get()) != EOF)
    {
        switch (grade)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                ++countA;
                break;

            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                ++countB;
                break;

            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                ++countC;
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Wrong Entry";
                cout << endl;
                break;
        }
    }

    cout << "A count: " << countA << endl;
    cout << "B Count: " << countB << endl;
    cout << "C count: " << countC << endl;

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Why don't you put grade as `char`?

Comment: @rcs Because [`std::cin.get()` return an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: @rcs It works when I put grade as char (The first problem is still there though) I'm trying to understand why the program still works when grade is an integer.

Comment: and you should use `char grade` and `while(cin>>grade)...`

Comment: did u try printing out grade? its printing out for a 9710

Comment: which is the ascii value i guess..

Comment: Yup, it printed out 97 for 'a'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am guessing that your enter your input as:

A followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
B followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
C followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

etc.

When you do that,

The first call to `cin::get()` returns `'A'`.
The next call to  `cin::get()` returns `'\n'`, the newline character.
The next call to `cin::get()` returns `'B'`.
The next call to  `cin::get()` returns `'\n'`.
The next call to `cin::get()` returns `'C'`.
The next call to  `cin::get()` returns `'\n'`.

etc.

Hence, after every "successful" processing of the characters that you perceive as valid input, it also processes the newline characters, which is processed by the `default:` section of the `switch` statement.

If you add code to ignore the newline, you won't see the output printed from the `default:` clause:

```
case '\n':
   break;
```

---

If you want to be able to ignore all whitespace characters, you can use:

```
char grade;
while ( std::cin >> grade )
{
   ...
}
```

If you do that, you won't need code to handle the newline character in the `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely answered the first part! Do you know why it still works when even though 'grade' is holding an integer value, and is being compared with character values 'A','a','B'.... and so on?

Comment: @ricksanchez, when you enter `A`, the integer value returned by `cin.get()` is equal to the integral value of the character constant `'A'`.

Comment: Integral value being the ASCII value of constant 'A'?

Comment: @ricksanchez, normally yes but it is independent of the character encoding used by the platform. It will also work on computers that use [EBCDIC  encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).

Comment: Okay last question, so when I'm comparing the equality of an integer and character variable, what I'm really comparing is the value of the Integer variable, and the "Integral Value" of the character variable?